# Chrome OS - Enable Kiosk Virtual Keyboard

Tags: android, virtual-keyboard, google-chrome-os

I have an application running on Chrome OS in kiosk mode. The application is a packaged Android application. I would like the virtual keyboard to display when a user needs to enter text. When I sign into Chrome OS I see the virtual keyboard. However in the application I don't see it when I select a widget that enables text entry.

In the following post it appears there has been a setting added to the kiosk administration, however I cannot find it:
[Option to always enable keyboard for kiosk apps](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=376900)

Is this possible?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you referring to [a Chrome OS device with native Android app capability](https://developer.android.com/topic/arc/index.html), or are you referring to an Android app packaged via the ARC Welder?

Comment: An Android app packaged via the ARC Welder.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it to show by signing into the Chrome OS and navigating to: chrome://flags.

In the list I enabled a few things (not very scientific) such as:

- Enable touch events Mac, Windows Chrome OS
- Virtual Keyboard Chrome OS
- Floating virtual keyboard. Chrome OS

(I have yet to test on a touch screen, however the keyboard itself is showing)

**NB:** This does not work if the application is on a device that is enrolled in a domain even if "Disable virtual keyboard" is disabled in the Admin console under Device management > App Management > "app_name" > Kiosk settings

Comment: This is not working now. any update?

I have used this thing before and it was work at that time.

Comment: Sorry - no idea. I'm not working with this any longer.